# How to split parenthesis and , in Java

Tags: java

I want to split this string (1,0) and get result 1 and 0 i have tried this code:

```
String str ="(1,0)";
String parts[]= str.split("(,)");
System.out.println(parts[0]);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

But i got this :

(1

0)

Comment: Why can't you simply take str[1] and str[3]?

Comment: @CodeTalker: Presumably, there can be numbers longer than a single digit.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, didn't think of that. I went specifically for the asked string.

Comment: You could replaceAll brackets and then its a simple split. Less code than writing pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "(1,0)";
        String parts[] = str.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",");
        System.out.println(parts[0]);
        System.out.println(parts[1]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
```

Comment: I applied your code to my program and it works. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an efficient way you can isolate all your digits using the [Regex Tools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) and put them into an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for easy usage. It doesn't use the `.split()` method, but it is efficient.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "(1,0)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    ArrayList<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();

    while(m.find())
      vals.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));

    System.out.println(vals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split on `(`, the first value in the returned array will be `""`.

I'd recommend using regex directly, e.g.

```
String input = "(1,0)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^,\\)]+),([^,\\)]+)\\)").matcher(input);
if (! m.matches())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: " + input);
System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

Of course, if you insist on using `split()`, it can be done like this:

```
String input = "(1,0)";
String[] parts = input.split("[(,)]");
if (parts.length != 3 || ! parts[0].isEmpty())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: " + input);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
System.out.println(parts[2]);
```

Comment: OK, so basically all that was required was the addition of two characters to the OP's existing code (the square brackets)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, that's not all. The indexes into `parts` are different, and I added the much needed validation.

Comment: Fair enough.  But the brackets do make the split work.

Comment: I'm just wondering what all the added complexity of the "regex directly" solution buys you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Better validation of the input, e.g. the split would allow inputs like '")1(0"' and `",1(0,,),,(()),,"` without error, the regex would correctly reject those as "Invalid input".

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use regex, go for that. (personally I prefer to use string manipulation here because it's really easier) If not, learn how to use it or do something like this:

```
String input = "(64,128)";
String[] numbers = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming your format is consistent.

```
        String str = "(1,0)";
        String[] tokens = str.substring(1,str.length()-1).split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Prints

```
[1, 0]
```

or if printed separately

```
1
0
```